# Git Deploying - Disabling plugin/theme installation/update on remote?

Tags: updates, git, deployment

Is there any way to disable the installation/updating of plugins in Wordpress?

I am deploying by Github, and therefore changes on server, does not replicate on my development environment.

I need to disable this, and make all updates and installations on my local Git repository, and THEN push to production, with the changes.

Comment: This means that the client can't add plugins themselves which can sometimes be undesirable. If you did want clients to be able to do this, but still sync between stages you could instead exclude plugins from the GIT repo and rsync the plugins folder, extra easy when done with Capistrano - at least that's how we do it. Just another option to consider.

Comment: It's not for a client, I do full service on the site!
- I'll take a look at Capistrano - Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the constant `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` to `TRUE` in your `wp-config.php`:

```
const DISALLOW_FILE_MODS = TRUE;
```

See [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_the_Plugin_and_Theme_Editor) for background information:

> Setting this constant also disables the Plugin and Theme editor (i.e. you don't need to set `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` and `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT`, as on its own `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` will have the same effect).

It will also prevent installing or uninstalling plugins, themes and updating the WordPress core.

This will not affect the Git deployment.

Comment: This is only for editing, right? How about actually installing/uninstalling plugins from the Plugin page?

Comment: @FrederikSpang This prevents everything. See my update.

Comment: This may just be preference of core, but all the constants in wp-config.php are set using `define()` instead of `const`, probably because of the global use of them. 
`define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );` matches the rest of the config file structure.

Comment: @morganestes The difference is that `define()` can evaluate expressions, while `const` cannot (and requires PHP 5.3). Not needed here. Use `const` for simple definitions, it is easier to read and to write.

Comment: @toscho Thanks for the info. I always wondered why there were two different ways and never knew when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few related bits you can tinker with, but the one most comprehensive setting for version controlled stack is `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );`. It will disable anything related to changing code files, core or extensions either.