# Show media-uploads to all users

Tags: plugins, functions, user-roles

I want my media-library and all currently uploaded files distributed and available to all users. I am using the [User Role Editor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Is there any functions.php hack that makes all media-uploads visible to all users and roles?

I have a subscriber that is possible to edit a few pages and upload media, but the media uploads that are currently in the library for admins are not visible to the subscriber.

Update: My current approach, that is not working so far.

my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'rk_shared_uploads' );
add_action( 'init', 'rk_shared_uploads');

function rk_shared_uploads() {
    $subscriber = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    $subscriber->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
    $subscriber->add_cap( 'unfiltered_upload' );

    $contributor = get_role( 'contributor' );
    $contributor->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
    $contributor->add_cap( 'unfiltered_upload' );

    $author = get_role( 'author' );
    $author->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
    $author->add_cap( 'unfiltered_upload' );
}
```

in my wp-config.php

```
const PP_MEDIA_LIB_UNFILTERED = true;
```

Comment: Add `upload_files` capability to user roles you want media library access.

Comment: The users are able to "upload" … I want them to see and use existing material in the library from all other users.

Comment: `upload_files` capability gives access to media and media-> add new. codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#upload_files)

Comment: See my question-update, I added this to my theme functions.php file. The user I tried has role "author" but can't see any media uploads.

Comment: Maybe with the RoleScoper Plugin this does not work?

Comment: Function name you have hooked is `allow_uploads` and your function name in a definition is `allow_contributor_uploads`. Is that typo or code not working?

Comment: Sorry, that was a type, code is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you mentioned is only reportedly tested up to WordPress version 3.6.1.

I would not (in general) recommend abandoned plugins, because they might impose security risks.

Additionally it uses PHP4 class constructors, that might soon be deprecated and it calls non static methods in a static way.

If you remove the plugin, you should be able to use your code snippet:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mathiregister_allow_uploads' );

function mathiregister_allow_uploads() {
    $contributor = get_role( 'contributor' );
    $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

to allow `contributors` to get access to the media library and upload files.

*Remember to prefix your filter callbacks, to avoid name collisions*.

ps: Skimming through the plugin code, you might be able to bypass the plugin's media restrictions by defining:

```
define( 'SCOPER_ALL_UPLOADS_EDITABLE ', true );
```

or do it [@toscho style](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191560/26350):

```
const SCOPER_ALL_UPLOADS_EDITABLE = true;
```

in the global scope, for example in your `wp-config.php` file.

But you should really consider using up-to-date plugins.

Comment: Thank you; I'll give that a try tomorrow. Is there any recomendation for a plugin that does what role-scoper is doing? I want to be able to restrict certain users to certain pages only?

Comment: Plugin & theme recommendations are off topic here on WPSE but on the [plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) there's the following notice:  *Role Scoper is no longer actively developed* and the plugin author also  mentions the successor plugin. @mathiregister

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded to the new plugin that the author is mentioning (even the paid one) but this feature is still not working. Unfortunately also not with your function. Do you think you can try the "User Role Editor" plugin with a subscriber role and give your function a try. I doesn't work for me.

Comment: It looks like the constant is called `PP_MEDIA_LIB_UNFILTERED` in the new version, you could try that in addition to your `upload_files` capability function. @mathiregister

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question again with my final approach, still no luck.

Comment: When I install the plugin, without any config changes and login in as a contributor or subscriber, with the `upload_files` capability, then I can see all the Media files. You could additionally try higher priority on your `rk_shared_uploads` and maybe test if the `edit_files` capability makes any difference. @mathiregister

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `unfiltered_upload` capability too?

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );

    $role->add_cap( 'upload_files' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_upload' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
add_action( 'init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Comment: I updated my question with my final approach, but with no luck.

Comment: I tested your updated code. It works fine. May be the plugin you use is conflicting with the code. Try adding priority in the `add_action` hook `add_action( 'admin_init', 'rk_shared_uploads', 15 );`
`add_action( 'init', 'rk_shared_uploads', 15);`

Answer (score -2):

I have not tested but the following code will help you please add the following two lines of code to your function.php file

```
$role= get_role([role_name ]);
$role->add_cap('upload_files');
```